# How do I link a table from one connection to another in SQL?

Tags: sql, database, join, hyperlink

I need to link data from a table in one sql connection to a table in another sql connection, and combine them to make one table (inner join).

How could I achieve it?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Product specific issue.)

Comment: What do you mean by "table in connection"? Are you talking about some temporary tables? Generally permanent tables are not somehow bound to client connections in most of DBMS.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to connect databases in two different servers,You can add of them as linked server.

[image]

Then you can access the data from that server, for example if you are adding server1,then you can access the table using the following query.

```
SELECT * 
FROM server1.YourDatabaseName.YourSchemaName.YourTableName
```

If you wanted to access from a different Database of the same server.Then use the following code for accaeeing the table data.

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM YourDatabaseName.YourSchemaName.YourTableName
```